# Emacs. Helm package. How find files in folder (not a git folder) and all subfolders?

Tags: file, emacs, emacs-helm

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1, Helm package.

To find file (e.g. **myfile.txt**) in any folder (not git, not project file) I use command **helm-find-file**. It's work. OK.

But now I need to find **myfile.txt** in current folder AND all subfolders. How I can do this by **helm** package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two ways that should work for you. In both cases, first use `helm-find-files`.

1) Once you're in the directory that you want to start your search from, hit `C-u C-x C-d` (this runs `helm-browse-project` recursively). Now you can type the filename that you're looking for and it should search in all subdirectories.

2) Alternatively, again from `helm-find-files`, hit `C-c /` (this effectively runs `find` (not sure how well this will work in Windows)).

Comment: not help. My folder is NOT project folder. It's simple folder.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Browse project will still do it. Did you try it?

Comment: I try but nothing happen. See screenshot

Comment: from Emacs documentation: (helm-browse-project ARG)

Preconfigured helm to browse projects.
Browse files and see status of project with its vcs.
Only HG and GIT are supported for now.

Comment: I want to create a function that uses helm-find-files in a specific directory recursively. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using `helm-find-files` followed by the `C-c /` command effectively runs `helm-find` which lets you type in a filename to search for from the current directory. You can also just call `helm-find` directly or `helm-find-1` if calling from elisp code.

Comment: I'm not  more use helm. I use ido-mode.