# Auto suggestion in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to find a package in Emacs that when you are trying to find a file, suggests you all the possible completions as you type. These completions show up in the   temporary buffer. It's like zshell functionality in vim but automatic. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, software and library recommendation questions are not welcome on Stack Overflow. Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't really mean

`"all the possible completions"`

In every directory? On every mounted drive?

But there are multiple emacs packages that do versions of this and what you're asking is too general for a question on stackoverflow as a lot of the choice comes down to personal preference and the style in which packages do particular things.

Personally I use `helm` and `projectile`.
Other choices are `ido` and `ivy` and there are no doubt many others that might achieve something that resembles "all the possible completions" in a useful way.

Here's one example using `helm` [Emacs. Helm package. How find files in folder (not a git folder) and all subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072813/emacs-helm-package-how-find-files-in-folder-not-a-git-folder-and-all-subfold)

Comment: I meant in the current directory. I'm sorry for not mentioning that. Projectile was the package that I was looking for. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find completion for anything, use  [Company Mode](http://company-mode.github.io/).  It has multiple back-ends including 'files' and you can configure them. It's a text completion framework.  It is also more practical than listing all the completion possible for a given letters.